If $45\alpha+47\beta=30$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are integers of minimum absolute values, then value of ${\alpha}^2+{\beta}^2$ is equal to

If $45\alpha+47\beta=30$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are integers of minimum abosulute values, then value of ${\alpha}^2+{\beta}^2$ is equal to

My solution: Since $45\alpha+47\beta=30\implies \beta=\dfrac{30-45\alpha}{47}$
Hence $\beta=-15\left(\dfrac{3\alpha-2}{47}\right)$
$\implies \dfrac{\beta}{-15}=\dfrac{3\alpha-2}{47}$
Hence $\beta$ must be multiple of $15$ and $3\alpha-2$ will be multiple of $47$
And I found solution as $\alpha=-15$ and $\beta=15$
Is there any other method to solve this Question because this method is not convincing to me

Now since you have one solution, the general solution is given by $(-15 + 47t, 15 - 45t)$. Now, check for the minimum of $(-15+47t)^2 + (15-45t)^2$ over the integers.

A quick way to get to that solution is to note that if $\alpha=-\beta$ then the equation becomes $2\beta=30$.

$~45\alpha - 30~$ is a multiple of $~15,~$ 
so $~15 ~| ~47\beta \implies 15 ~| \beta.$
So, the obvious try is to use case work : $~\beta = 15~$ or $~\beta = -15,~$ determine whether either of these leads to a satisfying value of $~\alpha,~$ and then try to prove that you have minimized $~\alpha^2 + \beta^2.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~\beta = 15}$
$$(3 \times 15 \times \alpha) + (15 \times 47) = (15 \times 2) \implies $$
$$3\alpha + 47 = 2 \implies \alpha = -15.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~\beta = -15}$
$$(3 \times 15 \times \alpha) + (-15 \times 47) = (15 \times 2) \implies $$
$$3\alpha - 47 = 2 \implies 3\alpha = 49.$$
This doesn't work, so Case 2 is rejected.

So, the problem is reduced to showing that $~(\alpha,\beta) = (-15,15)~$ minimizes $~\alpha^2 + \beta^2.$
Actually, this is an immediate result, because $~|\beta| \geq 30~$ must yield a larger value of $~\alpha^2 + \beta^2, ~$ and you know that $~15 ~| ~\beta.$

Actually, the stated problem is ambiguous, because it is asking for the minimum absolute values of $~\alpha~$ and $~\beta.~$
What exactly does this mean?  One interpretation is to minimize the sum $~(\alpha^2 + \beta^2).$
An alternative interpretation, might be that you are trying to minimize $~|~\alpha~| + |~\beta~|.~$
The above conclusion that the optimal values are $~(\alpha,\beta) = (-15,15)~$ is supported under this alternate interpretation, again because $~\beta~$ must be a multiple of $~15.$

Thanks to John Omeilan for noticing my oversight.  I have to prove that $~\beta = 0~$ is no good.
$$\beta = 0 \implies 45\alpha = 30,$$
which is impossible.

This is a good answer, but one minor issue is that, for completeness, it should explicitly exclude the possibility that $\beta = 0$.

@JohnOmielan Nice catch thanks.  Answer edited, covering $~\beta = 0~$ at the end of my answer.

$$45\alpha+47\beta=30$$
$$\implies45\alpha+45\beta=30-2\beta$$
$$\implies45(\alpha+\beta)=2(15-\beta)$$
Since 45 and 2 are co-prime, this equation would be satisfied iff $(\alpha+\beta)$ is some (say nth) multiple of 2 and $(15-\beta)$ is some (say mth) multiple of 45.
$$45.2n=2.45m\implies m=n$$
Hence,
$$(15-\beta)=45n$$
$$\beta=15-45n\tag1$$
$$(\alpha+\beta)=2n$$
$$\alpha=47n-15$$ Using (1)
This is the general solution for the equation.
Putting n=0 gives $\alpha=-15$ and $\beta=15$.
This results in $\alpha^2+\beta^2=450$.
Any change in n would increase the value of $\beta^2$ and n=1 would minimize this increase. This case would still yield the value of $\beta^2=900$ which in itself is greater than 450.
Hence, $\min\{\alpha^2+\beta^2\}=450$.
I would also recommend you to visit this libretexts page for similar problems on linear Diophantine equations.

As you pointed out, this is a linear Diophantine equation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the form of $m \alpha + n \beta = d$ (in our case $m = 45$ and $n = 47$). There is a "systematic" way of solving them as long as $d$ is a multiple of $\gcd(m,n)$.
Here $\gcd(45,47) =1$, so we can first find a pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ that satisfies the equation $45\alpha + 47 \beta = 1$ using Euclidean algorithm. The solution turns out to be $(23, -22)$, so $45 \cdot 23 + 47 \cdot (-22) = 1$. Multiplying 30 to both sides gives
$$45 \cdot (23\cdot 30) + 47 \cdot( (-22) \cdot 30) = 30$$
This tells us $(\alpha, \beta) = (690 , -660)$ is a set of solutions. The rest of them can be written as $(\alpha, \beta) = (690 - 47k, -660 + 45k)$. The solution you found can be achieved by plugging in $k = 15$. The questions asks for the minimum of $\alpha^2 + \beta^2$, which is quite easy after getting the general formula of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ because $\alpha^2 + \beta^2$ is just a quadratic in $k$.

This is a Bezout equation.
$$45a \equiv 30 \pmod {47}$$
$$47b = 30 - 45a$$
$$45a + 47b = 30 \tag{A1}$$
$$45a = 30 - 47b$$
$$30 \equiv 47b \pmod {45}$$
$$30 \equiv 2b \pmod {45}$$
$$30 - 2b = 45c \tag{B1} $$
$$30 - 45c = 2b$$
$$30 \equiv 45c \pmod 2$$
$$0 \equiv c \pmod 2$$
$$c = 0$$
$$30 - 2b = 45 \times 0 \tag{B2}$$
$$b = 15$$
$$45a + 47 \times 15 = 30 \tag{A2}$$
$$a = -15$$
